# Is it possible to build cmake projects directly using MSBuildTools

Tags: cmake, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

Currently we are planning to use VS2017 with a cmake project. Inside Visual Studio this works quite like a charm.

Now want to run our builds as part of CI on a dedicated build master running MSBuildTools.

Is it possible to directly run the build using the msbuild command, without creating solution files with cmake? Optimally, I would even use the CMakeSettings.json used from VS2017.

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT Unfortunately I have not resolved my issue yet. But I tried to fill my question on the team blog.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [build-tool-mode](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/manual/cmake.1.html#build-tool-mode) of `CMake` for this. It uses the underlying default build tool which is `MSBuild` for Visual Studio Generators.
From the build directory call:

```
cmake --build . --target ALL_BUILD --config Release -- /nologo /verbosity:minimal /maxcpucount
```

and you get a fast, nearly quiet build. To install use `INSTALL` target, for running your tests if configured use `RUN_TESTS` target.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I knew about that. What I am interested in, is it possible to even use the CMakeSettings.json used in VS2017?

Comment: I am not aware of such a feature.

Comment: Pretty useful command, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to directly run the build using the msbuild command, without creating solution files with cmake?
>
> Is it possible to directly run the build using the msbuild command, without creating solution files with cmake?

As far as I know, CMake produces Visual Studio Projects and Solutions seamlessly. So you can produce projects/solutions.

The **only tricky part** is to remember to make any changes in the cmake files, rather than from within Visual Studio.

In particular, each CMake project will create a Visual Studio solution (`.sln` file), while all of the CMake targets belonging to that CMake project will appear as Visual Studio projects within the corresponding solution.

```
CMake       Visual Studio

project <-> Solution (.sln)
Target  <-> Project (.vcxproj)
```

You can check [cmake-and-visual-studio](https://cognitivewaves.wordpress.com/cmake-and-visual-studio/) for more details.

Since MSbuild can build both solution files and project files, so you could also call `msbuild INSTALL.vcxproj`

> Is it possible to even use the CMakeSettings.json used in VS2017?

The answer is yes, check [the blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/11/16/cmake-support-in-visual-studio-the-visual-studio-2017-rc-update/) for details.

> If your CMake project requires additional settings to configure the
> CMake cache correctly, you can customize these settings by creating a
> CMakeSettings.json file in the same folder with the root
> CMakeLists.txt. In this file you can specify as many CMake
> configurations as you need – you will be able to switch between them
> at any time.
>
> You can create the CMakeSettings.json file by selecting the Project >
> Edit Settings > path-to-CMakeLists (configuration-name) menu entry.